# Calculate daily working hours from the mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate total work hour based on my punch table. punch table contains all the in and out punch time in it. consider first entry as in and second entry for same person as out. now calculate total working hour based on work time between in and out session.
I check old solution but none of this worked in my situation.
[SQL Fiddle link link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4c328/3)

```
CREATE TABLE `punch_data` (
  `id` double NOT NULL,
  `machine_no` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_card_no` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `flag` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `punch_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `punch_time` time NOT NULL,
  `day` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `month` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `r_code` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `mflag` char(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
INSERT INTO `punch_data` (`id`, `machine_no`, `emp_card_no`, `flag`, `punch_date`, `punch_time`, `day`, `month`, `year`, `r_code`, `mflag`) VALUES 
(20547, '01', '00000009', 'F', '2020-12-30 08:28:22', '08:28:22', '30', '12', '2020', '', ''),
(20551, '01', '00000005', 'F', '2020-12-30 09:43:28', '09:43:28', '30', '12', '2020', '', ''),
(20559, '01', '00000009', 'F', '2020-12-30 13:52:13', '13:52:13', '30', '12', '2020', '', ''),
(20561, '01', '00000005', 'F', '2020-12-30 14:26:01', '14:26:01', '30', '12', '2020', '', ''),
(20563, '01', '00000005', 'F', '2020-12-30 14:48:51', '14:48:51', '30', '12', '2020', '', ''),
(20564, '01', '00000009', 'F', '2020-12-30 15:34:33', '15:34:33', '30', '12', '2020', '', ''),
(20566, '01', '00000005', 'F', '2020-12-30 18:21:56', '18:21:56', '30', '12', '2020', '', ''),
(20569, '01', '00000009', 'F', '2020-12-30 18:47:06', '18:47:06', '30', '12', '2020', '', '')
```

calculate total hour like

```
Date          emp_card_no  total_work_hour
2020-12-30    00000009     09:06:43
2020-12-30    00000005     08:12:53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT machine_no, emp_card_no, DATE(punch_date) punch_date, SUM(delta) spent
FROM ( SELECT punch_data.*,
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @prev_date, punch_date) delta,
              @prev_date := CASE WHEN @prev_date IS NULL
                                 THEN punch_date
                                 ELSE NULL END dummy
       FROM punch_data
       CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @prev_date := NULL ) var
       -- WHERE ...
       ORDER BY machine_no, emp_card_no, punch_date ) subq
GROUP BY machine_no, emp_card_no, DATE(punch_date)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ab03947c4451650400af1143558cd74e

Comment: I am getting problem in this query when trying calculate time for the month and if entry in odd no then next date display wrong total time https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=20b2fcef6c79f2e271ab54a043212f57 please check fiddle link

Comment: @HiteshTripathi You tell: "consider first entry as in and second entry for same person as out". I.e. the amount of rows **must** be even. Your fiddle contains odd rows amount - i.e. it contradicts the task. Of course the solution cannot produce correct output.

Comment: you are 100 % right I asked for that things but now when i am implementing this system i found many days is missing out punch but i need to calculate daily work time of them should i have to ask different question for it?

Comment: @HiteshTripathi Of course you must ask new question (you may refer to this Q in it, of course). But when you have no mark does the row is IN or OUT event you have no chance to solve until some assumption is made - for example that the former row for a day is IN, the latter is OUT, all another for this day are errorneous and must be ignored.

Comment: ok thank you for your support